Is the variance of a product of a normal and an arbitrary density uniformly bounded with respect to the mean of the normal density?
Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be two probability density functions, where $f(x)$ is a normal density with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.
Define the new product density
$$
h(x) = \frac{f(x)g(x)}{Z(\mu)}, \quad Z(\mu) = \int f(y)g(y)dy.
$$
I am interested in the variance of $h(x)$:
$$
\text{Var}(h) = \int (x - \mathbb{E}[h])^2 h(x) dx, \quad \mathbb{E}[h] = \int x h(x) dx.
$$
For various choices of $g(x)$ (e.g., exponential, Student's t, lognormal), numerical experiments suggest that the variance of $h(x)$ is uniformly bounded in $\mu$. Theoretically, this result can easily be proved when $g(x)$ is a normal density.
My Questions:

Does this result hold true for a wide class of densities $g(x)$?
What are the minimal assumptions on $g(x)$ (e.g., tail decay, integrability) required to ensure that $\text{Var}(h)$ is uniformly bounded in $\mu$?
Does this uniform boundedness break down for densities $g(x)$ with extremely heavy tails (e.g., Cauchy distribution)?

Any insights or references to related results in probability theory would be greatly appreciated!

I assume that $\sigma=1$ for simplicity, and I denote $f_1(x)=e^{-x^2/2}f(x)dx$ then the new probability $h_{\mu} $ belongs to the exponential family generated by $f_1$. The Laplace transform $L$ of $f_1$ is    $L(\mu)=e^{\mu^2/2}Z(\mu)=e^{k(\mu)}$ where $k$ is the cumulant function. From the classical theory  if $X$ has density $h_{\mu}$ then the mean of $X$ is $m=k'(\mu)$ and the variance is $k''(\mu).$ If one parameterises by $m$ the variance is $V(m)$ your question is 'is $m\mapsto V(m)$  bounded? The variance function $V$ is obviously bounded if $f$ has bounded support or is normal (in the normal case $V$ is  constant). I must say that out of these cases I have never seen an explicit case where the variance function is bounded. However, the $ f_1$ is not quite arbitrary since $e^{x^2/2}f_1(x)$ is integrable, which makes of $f_1$ a very concentrated function. Explicit examples of this situation for which computation is feasible are lacking. The question is interesting.
Edit. I have interwied Shaul Barlev, an expert in exponential families. He suggests to use a form of the Brascamp Lieb inequality which says that if $X\sim e^{-g}dx$ where $g$ is convex and with a continuous second derivative, then the variance of $X$ is less than $1/\inf g''(x).$ Applying this to $g(x)=\sigma^2x^2/2 +x^4$ produces  a bounded non trivial variance function
$\leq 1/\sigma^2.$

Many thanks for this point of view! I'm exploring now Laplace transforms and exponential families of densities to shed some light on this topic.
